# Unity Dotween Pro animation + animator play not playing in 1 frame

Tags: unity-game-engine, dotween

The dotween animation is play first, then on second frame the animator.Play start to fire off.[image]

The issue is they are not run in 1 frame, so what happen is, User can see the tail of the kitty snapping of.

Before I execute above unity event, the kitty is in "idle_with_tail".